# Не считывает данные из базы данных SQL Qt

Tags: c++, sql, qt

Перекрестно создается база данных и заполняется, но вот пройти её и считать весь столбик "BarCode" почему-то не выходит.

```
void DataBase::readDataBase()
{
   QSqlQuery query;
   QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
   qDebug() << " QSqlRecord rec = query.record();";

   int BarCode;
   qDebug() << "while(query.next()) N";
   while(query.next()){
      BarCode = query.value(rec.indexOf("BarCode")).toInt();
      qDebug() << "BarCode :" <<BarCode;
   }
   qDebug() << "while(query.next()) K";
}
```

Вот вывод :

```
db->readDataBase();
 QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
while(query.next()) N
while(query.next()) K
```

Но почему то но не считывает и не отрабатывает массив. Хотя данные в базе есть, как и сама база данных.

Код этот из книги Макса Шлее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теперь заходит, надо было добавить вызов.

> SELECT * FROM  имя_таблицы

Вот функция исправленная, которая теперь работает :

```
void DataBase::readDataBase()
{
    // считываем данные из базы
    QSqlQuery query;

    if(!query.exec("SELECT * FROM " TABLE ";")){
        qDebug() << "Unable to execute query - exiting";
    }

    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();

    int BarCode;

    while(query.next()){
        BarCode = query.value(rec.indexOf("BarCode")).toInt();
        qDebug() << "BarCode :" <<BarCode;
    }
}
```